# Error: storage/object-not-found when trying to upload large image file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, rxfire

I'm getting an error : storage/object-not-found when trying to upload a large image file in Google Cloud Storage using RxFire.

They say the image is not found in the bucket but when I check, i see them!

I tested with small images (100kb likely...) works great.

But tried with > 500kb images, doesn't work...

```
upload$
  .pipe(
    switchMap((event: any) => {
      const name = Math.random().toString(36).substring(5);
      const blob = event.target.files[0];
      const type = blob.type.replace('image/', '');
      const ref = storage.ref(`uploads/test/${name}.${type}`);
      return put(ref, blob);
    }),
    map(snapshot => snapshot),
    filter(snapshot => snapshot.totalBytes === snapshot.bytesTransferred),
    mergeMap(snapshot => getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref))
  )
  .subscribe(url => {
    console.log('Results', url)
  }, (error) => {
    // ERROR HERE
    console.log('error', error)
  })
```

Expected result : Upload working with big images

Actual results : Error

```
Uncaught t {code_: "storage/object-not-found", message_: "Firebase . 
Storage: Object 'uploads/test/7xpbilmb.jpeg' does not exist.", 
serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 404,↵    "message": 
"Not Found.  Could not get object"↵  }↵}", name_: "FirebaseError"}
```

Comment: I'd guess that getDownloadURL is somehow getting called before the upload is fully complete.

Comment: Hey, yeah that's wierd.. with 8kb files, it works, but when I reach around 300kb, this error appears. I'm waiting bytes transferred === the total bytes.. but maybe thats not enough?

Comment: With the regular javascript APIS, you wait for the UploadTask promise to resolve, or you wait for the UploadTaskSnapshot state to be "SUCCESS".

Comment: alright, i'm using promises now with the regular .put() method and it works fine... thanks. But if someone has the same problem with RxJs, feel free to share :D

Comment: I've had that problem when `AngularFireStorageReference` and `AngularFireUploadTask` referred to a different file name due to my mistake including in one of them timestamp, and in other not. Finally, variable declaration such as `const fileName = file.name + '_' + Date.now();` and reference in both of these objects created by `AngularFireStorageReference` and `AngularFireUploadTask` did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it both ways.

1. Promises

   ```
    storageRef.put(blob, {customMetadata}).then(data => {
                   data.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                       // do whatever you want with url
                   });
               });
   ```
2. Observables

   ```
   downloadURL = new Subject();
   this.downloadURL.pipe(
                   map(obs => obs),
                   concatAll()
               ).subscribe(url => {
                   // do whatever you want with url
               });

   let task = ref.put(blob, {customMetadata});
   task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
                   finalize(() => this.downloadURL.next(ref.getDownloadURL()))
               ).subscribe();
   ```

This should be enough to get you your downloadURL. In case you wanna track upload progress with observables, here's the code for that:

```
task.percentageChanges().subscribe(progress => {
                console.log('upload progress: ', progress);
                if (res >= 100) {
                    // HOORAY!
                }
            });
```